# Make anchor tag size to its div content?

Tags: html, css

Below is a test file, `test.htm`, which results with this in Firefox:

[image: testhtm]

The `<div>` is green with yellow border and specified size, and the `<a>` is with red border. Clearly, the anchor tag has both larger width and height that the div that it contains. How can I make the anchor tag equal in size to its div contents - however, in such a way that the size and position of the `<div>` is unchanged? Basically, for this example and the browser window size shown, I'd want this (manually edited pic):

[image: testhtm2]

`test.htm`:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <style type="text/css">
body {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  color: darkred;
}
div#button {
  margin-top: 2vh;
  padding: 2em;
  width: 20em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: yellow;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3vh;
  /* to center div horizontally: */
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none; /*remove underline of a href link:*/
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: unset;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: red;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<br/>
<a href="test.zip" target="_blank"><div id="button">Download this</div></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Depending on how it is being used you could set it to `display: inline-block;` instead of `display: block;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the `a` from `display: block;` to `display: inline-block;`.
In order to get the exact same height, remove the `margin-top` of the div.

In order to keep it centered, add `text-align:center` to the parent element, in your case your `body`. Note: in this way, everything inside the body will be centered.
If you only want your `a`-tag be centered, add a wrapper div around it and add the `text-align:center`.

Codepen example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jrNvzx

Comment: Many thanks @MichaelSchmidt; however that messes up the horizontal centering of the div (done with margin-left/right auto); I have clarified the OP with the results I want to get. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: @sdaau: add `text-align:center;` to your `body`. Note that everything inside of the body will be centered. Or add a wrapper around your HTML and. I updated the codepen demo

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelSchmidt - looks like the wrapper technique is what I'd need.. cheers!

Comment: @sdaau: Nice, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <style type="text/css">
body {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  color: darkred;
}
div#button {
  padding: 2em;
  width: 20em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: yellow;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3vh;
  /* to center div horizontally: */
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none; /*remove underline of a href link:*/
  display:inline-block;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: unset;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: red;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<br/>
<a href="test.zip" target="_blank"><div id="button">Download this</div></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @ AbhishekPandey, but this does the same as @MichaelSchmidt - and same as there, the horizontal centering is not preserved, which is what I'd want. Any suggestions for that?